# javascript XSL in google chrome

Tags: javascript, xslt, google-chrome

I'm using the following javascript code to display xml/xsl:

```
function loadXMLDoc(fname)
{
  var xmlDoc;
  // code for IE
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  }
  // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
  else if (document.implementation
  && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
    xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
   }
  else
  {
    alert('Your browser cannot handle this script');
  }
  try {
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.load(fname);
    return(xmlDoc);
    }
 catch(e)
 {
  try //Google Chrome
  {
   var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET",file,false);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
   xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
   return(xmlDoc);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
   error=e.message;
  }
 }
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("report.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("report.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
  // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
  else if (document.implementation
  && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
    xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
    document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
```

It works find for IE and Firefox but chrome is fail in the line:

```
document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Chrome currently has limited support for XSL. If your XSL refers to any external resources (`document()` function, `xsl:import`, `xsl:include` or external entities), the XSL will run but the result will either be empty or invalid.

If that's not the cause of your problem, the issue can be different: `resultDocument` and `document` do not share the same root. Try to use [importNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.importNode) or a similar technique. If that fails and you're certain that resultDocument has valid contents, transform it to a string, add a node manually, and set `innerHTML` of the new node to the string. I know, it's ugly, but until Chrome becomes mature we'll need some workarounds...

Answer (score 3):

I have found that Chrome (for tr and td tags at least), requires well formed html.  Eg you cannot start at tr - it must be in a tbody (or thead), but you can't start there either, it must be placed inside a table tag... (I don't think the xslt engine is forgiving on the rules of html - even if you are trying to form a fragment.)

So if you want table from an xslt - do the whole thing, not a part.  Ie Do this:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

NOT THIS:

```
<tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
```

OR THIS:

```
<tr><td></td></tr>
```

Or in my experience, the tr tags got lost and it just looked like a lot of text.